# Counting TOTAL number of rows in the tables of a database

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to know how to Count the TOTAL number of rows in the tables of a database. For example, I have 3 tables in a database called:

**Table 1**: *5 rows*

**Table 2**: *4 rows*

**Table 3**: *3 rows*

So the output should be: **12 rows**.

I know how to count rows in a specific table. Is there something to loop here?

Thanks.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/tables-table.html shows a schema table containing a rough count of the rows.  if you need an exact count, you could use data in the information schema to query each table and get the exact counts.

Comment: Thanks Rob. That worked out.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT sum(cnt) AS overall_cnt
FROM (
    SELECT count(*) AS cnt FROM table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT count(*) AS cnt FROM table2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT count(*) AS cnt FROM table3
) AS foo
```

Comment: No no. I mean what if I have like thousands of tables? Is there like a loop or something?

Comment: not in a regular query. you could build a stored procedure that queries the information schema tables and loop on those results.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT sum(TABLE_ROWS)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME IN ('table1', 'table2', 'table3');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(TABLE_ROWS)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db_name';
```

[image]